# can I would like to make a multiple iteration with a single loop Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I would like to make these multiple iterations in one single loop, but I don't know how it works.
I'm reading the database of daily demand and sending it to the wholesaler agent if the demand is greater than the current stock of the retailer.

```
// read demand from DBs that send orders to wholesaler1
int today = 1;
retailers(0).dailyDemand = (int) selectFrom(ddr1)
    .where(ddr1.day.eq(today))
    .firstResult(ddr1.demand);
wholesaler1.retailersDemand = retailers(0).dailyDemand;     
retailers(1).dailyDemand = (int) selectFrom(ddr2)
    .where(ddr2.day.eq(today))
    .firstResult(ddr2.demand);
wholesaler1.retailersDemand = retailers(1).dailyDemand; 
retailers(2).dailyDemand = (int) selectFrom(ddr3)
    .where(ddr3.day.eq(today))
    .firstResult(ddr3.demand);
wholesaler1.retailersDemand = retailers(2).dailyDemand;
retailers(3).dailyDemand = (int) selectFrom(ddr4)
    .where(ddr4.day.eq(today))
    .firstResult(ddr4.demand);
wholesaler1.retailersDemand = retailers(3).dailyDemand; 
retailers(4).dailyDemand = (int) selectFrom(ddr5)
    .where(ddr5.day.eq(today))
    .firstResult(ddr5.demand);
wholesaler1.retailersDemand = retailers(4).dailyDemand; 
// read demand from DBs that send orders to wholesaler2
wholesaler2.retailersDemand = retailers(5).dailyDemand; 
retailers(5).dailyDemand = (int) selectFrom(ddr6)
    .where(ddr6.day.eq(today))
    .firstResult(ddr6.demand);
wholesaler2.retailersDemand = retailers(5).dailyDemand; 
today++;
```

the screenshot illustrates what I mean
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R38X1.png)
[Agents List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gekvf.png)

Comment: can you put everything in one table instead of using multiple tables (ddr1, ddr2 etc)?

Comment: I can't because each retailer has his own daily demand (in my logic)

Comment: you can have 1 table with the demand information for each retailer.. this would make it easier to loop

Comment: should I add all the demands in one sheet?

Comment: yes you should... once you do that, show the resulting table that you created and I'll tell you how to do the loop

Comment: I did what you told me :

Comment: (top of the database) https://ibb.co/6XVT4qg  (down of the database) https://ibb.co/0YPnct2

Comment: I created 2 events, each one to read for five retailer's databases like in those screens (readDemandG1 event) https://ibb.co/x5RYVdY (readDemandG2 event) https://ibb.co/8g4kxqF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following, mainting the name of the columns with the format you have

```
Tuple t = selectFrom(daily_demand_retailers)
    .where(daily_demand_retailers.day.eq(today))
    .list().get(0);
        
daily_demand_retailers.getColumns().forEach(col->{
    String colName = col.getMetadata().getName(); 
    if (!colName.equals("al_id")
            && !colName.equals("day")
            ) {
        int id=Integer.parseInt(colName.split("_r")[1]);
        
        retailers.get(id-1).dailyDemand=(int)t.get(col);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer I'll try it and tell you the results , But I have a question, should I add this 10 times and add each time the column name ? or it gonna be scaling automatic ?

Comment: I got this problem https://ibb.co/kXmRCgY  (Description: The method get(int) is undefined for the type Qretailers)

Comment: it will be automatic... and the error is because your database is called the same way as your agents... change your table name to retailers_db

Comment: I changed the database name as you told me, but still the same issue

Comment: show me all your database

Comment: https://ibb.co/23stjpY
https://ibb.co/Xx1yC43

Comment: your database, not your table.. i want to see the list of all the tables that you have in your database... i bet there's one called retailers

Comment: https://ibb.co/cNYj6Xr

Comment: Ok I give up helping you... i told you that i wanted to see the tables.. but if you refuse to do that, then you are on your own... good luck

Comment: I'm sorry I though that you want what I have of agents sorry : https://ibb.co/Bt23SGq

Comment: I have so many tables in the database I create each one individual because I don't know how to make the loop

Comment: well with that I'm pretty sure this is all a prank.. you clearly have a table called retailers even though you insisted that you didint... i told you days ago that this was your error and change the name to retailers_db...  so if you lie about the questions I ask, there's no point in helping you for free

Comment: I'm not lying about anything, it's just I can't merge the retailers (I have two groups of retailers), so I need to create the loop twice) why should I lie to get help? this makes no sense! The table retailers is not used in the model because I devised the content of this table and it's used for retailer group 1 and retailer group 2

Comment: Anyway Mr Felipe thank you for your help, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to load the daily demand (?):

Instead of using `int today = 1;` at the top (which would always stay 1 every day), you can simply use `int today = (int)time(DAY)` to get the current model time in days (rounded to the nearest integer)

Comment: Yes, sir, it's always 1, and it's a problem, and I don't know how to resolve it, thank you it's working now, but can you help me reduce the code with 1 for loop?

Comment: If it helped, please upvote the answer (helps others find it in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote ).